# Ext.Net: NumberField starts with number> 0

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

I would like this field kind NumberField starts with value 5 I tried using Numer = "5" and StartNumberField = "5". But without success.

the code is below.

```
<ext:ViewItem Value="NrField" BoundField="Nr">
    <Component>                                                                            
        <ext:NumberField ID="nbNr" runat="server" Numer = "5" StartNumberField = "5"  MinValue="0"   FieldLabel="Nr" LabelWidth="50">
            <Listeners>
                <Change Handler="if (App.cbTurn.getRawValue().substring(0,2) == 'PO') { if(this.value > 10) { this.setValue(10,10,true); Ext.Msg.alert('Warning','Max 10 Nr.'); } } else { if (this.value > 8) { this.setValue(8,8,true); Ext.Msg.alert('Warning','Max 8 Nr.'); }}" />
                <Blur Handler="if (this.value == null) {  this.setValue(0,0,true); }" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:NumberField>
    </Component>
</ext:ViewItem>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`Numer = "5"` should be  `Number="5"`